# What does "--log-file -" mean in Heroku procfile?

Tags: heroku

Looking through the updated "[Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)" guide, they have the following example procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```

What does the ***--log-file -*** mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "log to stdout". The `--log-file` flag lets you set a path to a log file, and `-` means "stdout" (in this context).

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming this is not a setting I'd want in production, right?

Comment: @Sologoub: It would actually make sense to send logging messages to stdout, since Heroku collection output from stdout and uses it in their own logging tools.